# Exclude rows with a column containing a value if multiple rows exist for

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table has

```
User   Value
john   284
john   200
john   5
sally  245
sally  180
sally  10
bill   90
bill   1000
bill   284
greg   10
greg   90
greg   2000
```

If User has a value of 284 for example, then I want the result set not to include him
I am not sure how to check all rows of User to see if there is the 284 value and then not show that user in the resultset if it is there.  The resultset should be distinct.

The end resultset should be

```
User
greg
sally
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `not exists`:

```
select distinct
    user
from
    users u
where
    not exists (
       select
           1
       from
           users u2
       where
           u2.user = u.user
           and u2.value = 284
    )
```

What this does is it grabs all the users from the `users` table where they don't have a row with the value `284` in the `users` table. You can also do `exists` as a converse (finding only users with a `284` value).

Additionally, use a `distinct` on the `select` to limit the users returned to their unique values.

Comment: I tried: select 
User,
Description,
linkId

from vw_Links e1
where User in (
'john','sally','bill','george')
and not exists (

select 1
from tbl_Users e2
where e2.User = e1.User
and importance > 3
and linkId in ('283','284','285')
)

order by e1.User ASC;  It still returns all rows for all users (even those with 284).

Comment: Are importance and linkid in e2?  Best to be explicit and specify e1. or e2. as appropriate.

Comment: The verbal description of what it should do is display distinct rows for a user that does not have 284 in any of the user's numerous rows.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Select distinct User from table
    where User not in ( Select User from table
    where value =284)
```

Comment: okay, I was able to take the last example and make that work for my need.  Thanks gang!

Comment: By the way, this wouldn't work if there were a row in the table with a NULL value for User (where value = 284).  If there were true you could include AND User IS NOT NULL to the subselect's where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.[User]
FROM users u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u2 ON u2.[User] = u1.[User] AND u2.Value = 284
WHERE u2.[User] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by user and also count how many users with value != 284

Here is SQL

```
Select   `User`
,count(*)- SUM(CASE WHEN `Value` != 284 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 284Val
from table
group by `User`
having 284Val = 0;
```