# Excluding rows from query results based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to remove all rows of column A values where column B = 'S'. Here is an example I could show with data:

```
    column A    column B
    100         S
    100         P
    100         C
    101         P
    101         C
    102         S
    103         C
    104         P
```

From here, I'd like eliminate all entries from column A that show 'S' in column B (100 and 102) so I'm left with:

```
column A    column B
    101         P
    101         C
    103         C
    104         P
```

I was trying to follow the steps from a similar SO post ([Exclude rows with a column containing a value if multiple rows exist for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826001/exclude-rows-with-a-column-containing-a-value-if-multiple-rows-exist-for)), but it kept excluding the rows where 'S' was present and keeping the shared column A values.

For example, here's the relevant parts of my query I'm working on:

```
select table_a.column_a
    ,table_b.column_b
    ,...
from table_z
inner join table_b
    on table_z.z = table_b.z
inner join table_y
    on table_z.y = table_y.y
left outer join table_a
    on table_x.x = table_a.x
where date > 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    and (
        table_b.column_b not in (
            select column_b
            from table_b
            where (column_b = 'S')
            )
        )
order by table_a.column_a
```

But it only removes rows where column_b = 'S' and does not remove the rows with a column_A value that match where column_b appears (column_a = 100 example from the beginning of this post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE column_A IN ( SELECT column_A FROM YourTable
                     EXCEPT
                     SELECT column_A FROM YourTable 
                      WHERE column_B = 'S' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ColumnA int,ColumnB varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(100,'S'),
(100,'P'),
(100,'C'),
(101,'P'),
(101,'C'),
(102,'S'),
(103,'C'),
(104,'P')

Select * 
 From  @YourTable
 Where ColumnA Not In (Select Distinct ColumnA From @YourTable where ColumnB='S')
```

Returns

```
ColumnA ColumnB
101     P
101     C
103     C
104     P
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Table_A, not Table_B in your sub-query in where clause:

```
    select *
from Table_A
where Column_B != 'S'
    and Column_A not in (
        select distinct column_A
        from Table_A
        where Column_B = 'S'
        )
```

Edited your query. This should work:

```
select table_a.column_a
    ,table_b.column_b
    ,...
from table_z
inner join table_b
    on table_z.z = table_b.z
inner join table_y
    on table_z.y = table_y.y
left outer join table_a
    on table_x.x = table_a.x
where date > 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    and table_a.column_b != 'S'
    and table_a.column_A not in (
        select distinct table_a.column_A
        from Table_A
        where Column_B = 'S'
        )
order by table_a.column_a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table_A as A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Table_B as B
  WHERE  B.ColumnA = A.ColumnA
  AND    B.ColumnB = 'S' )
```

This is very similar to another answer, except that it uses NOT EXISTS as opposed to NOT IN.  The IN keyword can very useful, but [using NOT IN should be avoided](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) for possible performance reasons.