# Exclude values from results if a column contains a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a SQL database where I receive the following data:

```
YEAR  | REFERENCE      | HEADER    | USER       | DATE        | ID            | Key      |
2019    Charity Funding              UCRP511      2020-01-15    0128923961US    
2019    Charity Funding              UCRP511      2020-01-15    0128923961US    JBOT_P10
2019    Charity Funding              UCRP511      2020-01-15    0128923961US    
2019    Charity Funding              UCRP511      2020-01-15    0128923961US    
2019    Charity Funding              UCRP511      2020-01-15    0128923961US    
2019    SJ/1019/233                  UCRP511      2020-01-10    
2019    Computer Comp                UCRP511      2020-01-15    024543342OS1    
2019    SJ/1019/231                  UCRP539      2020-01-10    
2019    PAYROLL (SC)    LABOR DIST   UCRP539      2020-01-10                    JBOT_P10
```

I have tried using the following solution:

[Exclude rows with a column containing a value if multiple rows exist for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826001/exclude-rows-with-a-column-containing-a-value-if-multiple-rows-exist-for)

Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM SDD.GenData s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SDD.GenData s2
    WHERE s2.ID = s1.ID AND s2.Key LIKE '%BOT_P10'
)
```

Here are the rules of what I am looking for:

- If ID is NOT blank ('') then the row stays
- If ID is NOT blank ('') ,but has a value in "Key" for one or more rows of the same ID then all rows with said ID must all be excluded.
- If ID is blank ('') and has a value in "Key" then the row is excluded.
- If ID is blank and Key is blank then row stays.

Here is an example of what I am expecting based off the input above..

```
YEAR  | REFERENCE      | HEADER    | USER     | DATE        | ID              | Key      |
2019    Computer Comp                UCRP511    2020-01-15    024543342OS1  
2019    SJ/1019/233                  UCRP511    2020-01-10    
2019    SJ/1019/231                  UCRP539    2020-01-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.id is null and t.[key] is null) or
      (not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.[key] is not null
                 ) and
       t.[key] is null
      );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(key) over (partition by id) as max_key
      from t
     ) t
where max_key is null or (id is null and [key] is null);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b58336e2cacf43ba81d249ce3d08340) is a db<>fiddle.

Your rules are not quite as you state them.  The rules appear to be:

- `id` is NULL and `key` is null; or
- There is no non-NULL `key` on a non-NULL `id`.

Comment: This does not appear to be working. I get no rows returned (for both queries)

Comment: @tastydew . . . Both queries returned rows, so I'm not sure why you were getting that nothing was returned.  However, neither returned exactly the set you wanted.  I've revised the queries and added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you your desired result; the first part of the `WHERE` clause excludes rows with a given `ID` value if any of them have the excluded `Key` value, and the second includes rows where the `ID` value is blank, as long as the `Key` value is not the excluded value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM GenData s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM GenData s2
                  WHERE s2.ID = s1.ID AND s2.[Key] LIKE '%BOT_P10'
                  )
  OR (ID = '' AND NOT [Key] LIKE '%BOT_P10')
```

Output:

```
YEAR    REFERENCE       HEADER  USER        DATE        ID              Key
2019    Computer Comp           UCRP511     2020-01-15  024543342OS1     
2019    SJ/1019/231             UCRP539     2020-01-10           
2019    SJ/1019/233             UCRP511     2020-01-10
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/825d2/3)

Comment: I have updated my question. I think the reason I don't get the same results is because i neglected to clarify that rows without values are NOT null, but simply blank (''). I tried modifying your response to change ID = '' in the last line but that doesn't seem to yield the correct results. I also clarified the exact rules I am looking for.

Comment: @tastydew See my edit. I think that does what you have described in your updated question.

Comment: @tastydew Did my edit answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?